# Autocad 2018 NETLOAD not showing my command method

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autocad-plugin

I'm trying to make a plug in for Autocad 2018 with Visual Studio 2019 using .Net 
Firstly, I am getting a warning in VS when the debug is "Any CPU" the bug goes off when I switch to x64.
After building the project and having the .dll file and I go to Autocad and load it using NETLOAD command, when I try to load my method or "CommandMethod" it doesn't show up.

- I tried changing the .Net Framework to whatever version I have from 4.7.2 to 4.5
- Tried different codes from other sources and still no results
  Should I use a higher version of AutoCad? or should I use a lower version of VS like 2017?
  What could be the problem?
  Here's the code:

  ```
  using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
  using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
  using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry;
  using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;
  using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
  using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Core;

  [assembly: CommandClass(typeof(Testing.Class1))]
     namespace Testing
  {
      public class Class1
      {
          [CommandMethod("MyFirstCommand")]
          public void my()
          {

          Document doc=Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
          Database db = doc.Database;
          Editor edt = doc.Editor;

          using (Transaction trans=db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
          {
              try
              {

                  BlockTable bt;
                  bt = trans.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;
                  BlockTableRecord btr;
                  btr = trans.GetObject(bt[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace], OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTableRecord;

                  // send message to the user
                  edt.WriteMessage("\nDrawing a line objet");

                  Point3d pt1 = new Point3d(0, 0, 0);
                  Point3d pt2 = new Point3d(100, 0, 0);

                  Line ln = new Line(pt1, pt2);
                  ln.ColorIndex = 1;
                  btr.AppendEntity(ln);
                  trans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(ln, true);
                  trans.Commit();
              }
              catch (System.Exception e)
              {
                  edt.WriteMessage("Error Encountered" + e.Message);
                  trans.Abort();
              }
          }
          edt.WriteMessage("Script loaded");

      }

  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your references. I have had problems with this in the past when I have a broken or incorrect reference.

Are any of your settings for your AutoCAD references different than the settings in the below image?

[image: AutoCAD Reference Properties Window]

Comment: Do you have any other AutoCAD .NET applications that are loading? Is there a chance that you might have another command with the same name and it is causing an error?

Comment: Also, could using `my()` for the name cause an issue?

Comment: I checked the references and I have the same inputs as your picture. However, my version is a bit old than yours apparently. I have 18.1.0.1. Also I don't think the function name is the problem I changed it different times and still the same problem.

Comment: SOLVED by adding the dll files from ObjecrARX folder called "inc" I had older versions of the dll files which they weren't compatible with AutoCad 2018, thanks !

Comment: Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 1):

class where You define `[CommandMethod("Command_Name")]` must be **`public`**

Answer (score 1):

> Waseememe wrote:
>
> SOLVED by adding the dll files from ObjecrARX folder called "inc" I had older versions of the dll files which they weren't compatible with AutoCad 2018, thanks ! – Waseememe Feb 18 at 22:38

As I cannot add any comments ill add this as an answer.

You should really add your references through the NuGet packages functionality built into Visual Studio. This will resolve any future problems related to this.

How? -→ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio
tldr: right click your project, click on manage NuGet packages, click the "Browse" tab, and search for the AutoCAD API packages, install them by using the UI to the right.

[image: manage nuget packages]
[image: UI to the right]

Where is the AutoCAD NuGet located on the net? -→ https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoCAD.NET/23.1.0/